# How to pass user defined class to wsdl in android using k2soap?

Tags: java, android, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I want to send 3 parameters to wsdl.Third parameter is array of BusStop Object.For busstops parameter I create "busStop" class.The service I used at below:

[image]

To pass this parameters I use this code below:

```
try {
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

                busStop busStop = new busStop();
                busStop.busStopId=99999;
                busStop.latitude=40.8f;
                busStop.longitude=29.3f;
                busStop.name="yeni";
                busStop.parentBusStopId=1;
                busStop.soundFile=null;
                busStop.stopType="1";
                busStop.validityStartDate="25.12.2014";
                busStop.validtyEndDate="30.12.2014";

                PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                pi.setName("busStop");
                pi.setValue(busStop);
                pi.setType(busStop.getClass());


                request.addProperty("id", "004");
                request.addProperty("user", "ABC");
                //request.addProperty("busstops",busstops);
                request.addProperty(pi);



               MarshalFloat md = new MarshalFloat();
               md.register(envelope);

               MarshalByte md2 = new MarshalByte();
               md2.register(envelope);

                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                Log.i("lolo",envelope.bodyOut.toString());
                HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                try {
                    transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD, envelope);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    resp = e.getMessage();

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                //bodyIn is the body object received with this envelope
                if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {
                    //getProperty() Returns a specific property at a certain index.
                    SoapObject resultSOAP = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn)
                            .getProperty(0);
                resp=resultSOAP.toString();



                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }
            return resp.toString();
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Response{return=anyType{resultCode=100; resultDefinition=Unable to resolve 'jdbc.dbnull'. Resolved 'jdbc'; }; }
```

I also try parameter like this:

```
request.addProperty("busStopId",busStop.busStopId);
request.addProperty("latitude",busStop.latitude);
................................and goes like this.
```

And I got the same error.I don't know how can I handle this problem.Because I'm so inexperienced in WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD2);

                //pass parameters to wsdl service
                request.addProperty("id", "004");
                request.addProperty("user", "ABC");

                SoapObject busstops = new SoapObject();
                busstops.addProperty("busStopId",77777);
                busstops.addProperty("latitude",40.854793f);
                busstops.addProperty("longitude",29.291694f);
                busstops.addProperty("name","dene");
                busstops.addProperty("stopType","1");
                busstops.addProperty("validityStartDate","17.01.2015");
                busstops.addProperty("validtyEndDate","30.01.2015");

                request.addProperty("busstops",busstops);
```

solves the problem.